# I can connect to a router on 192.168.2.1, but it's not my router. Whoose router is it?

Tags: networking, routing

I understand my router is located on 192.168.0.1
How can I be able to connect on another router on 192.168.2.1? If I understand correctly, 192.168.x.x is the private network, and only my routers can be located there, correct?

Comment: Your wireless is apparently connecting to a different nearby unsecured access point. Or you have two wireless access points of your own.

Comment: Where do you see `192.168.2.1`? A screenshot will help.

Answer (score 0):

> 192.168.x.x is the private network, and only my routers can be located there

Not necessarily. "Private" only means that such addresses won't go across the public Internet (all ISPs will refuse to route them). But it doesn't mean that this range is strictly limited to your single network – by default, routers will still forward such packets like everything else.

So if your router 1 (using 192.168.0.x) is connected to another *local* router 2 (using 192.168.2.x) – whether yours, or the landlord's, or something like that – then you'll be able to access it this way.

Use `tracert -n 192.168.2.1` to check how far away it is, network-wise.